# Sqoop Import Using Greenplum

Tags: sqoop

I want to import data into hive from greenplum using sqoop.

I am able to import successfully data from default schema of greenplum for user.

But, I am not able to fetch data from table present in other schemas of greenplum.

I tried various option.

Can you please help?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Which sqoop-version do you use? 
With v1.4.3 you can set schema-parameter.
With v1.4.2  you can use freeform query (--query) with schema.
I tried and it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Sqoop itself don't have a notion of "schema". Some specialized connectors (PostgreSQL, Microsoft SQL Server) are exposing user ability to specify a schema, but as Sqoop don't have specialized connector for Greenplum it won't help you here.

You should be able to use query-based import instead of table and specify the schema name in the query, e.g. something like:

```
sqoop import --query "select * from schema.tablename where $CONDITIONS"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can take the advantage of custom schema

try with

```
--schema <<schema_name>>
```